# iphone xCode use of undeclared identifier

Tags: objective-c

I just started programming in objective-c and I have a problem with "use of undeclared identifier 'uneImage'; did you mean '_uneImage'?". Lot of post speak about this but I haven't found the solution.

.h :

```
    #import 


    @interface ViewController : UIViewController 
    {
        UIImagePickerController *picker;
    }

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *uneImage;


    - (IBAction)album:(id)sender;
    @end
```

.m

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (IBAction)album:(id)sender
    {
        picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        uneImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define a property `xyz`, by default its name is transformed to `_xyz` to name its backing variable. You can override it with `@synthesize name;` or even `@synthesize name = someOtherName;`, but the use of `@synthesize` is no longer required.

The property itself is visible from the outside, but it does not introduce an unqualified name in the scope the same way the variables do. In other words, you cannot use the property without prefixing it with `self`, but you can use its backing variable.

To make the long story short, replace

```
uneImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

with

```
_uneImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

or

```
self.uneImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an instance variable named `uneImage`. You have a property with that name and an automatically synthesized instance variable named `_uneImage`.

So change:

```
uneImage.image = ...
```

to either:

```
self.uneImage.image = ... // use the property
```

or:

```
_uneImage.image = ... // use the generated instance variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a property, so you need to put "self" in front of the variable:

```
self.uneImage.image = ....
```